# Using multiple layers as point features in spatial join using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join

I have 15 point feature layers and one polygon layer. I need to count the total number of points in the polygon using a spatial join, to then classify the different polygons based on the join count.

Is there any way to do this with another task, because the spatial join wizard only allows me to use one point layer?

Comment: No, run the tool 15 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the number of points (no matter which point layer that they are coming from) within your polygons, you can [Merge](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) your points first and try to run [Spatial Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) tool with its default parameters. Join_Count field should give you what you are after.

Comment: thanks for the answer! do u think a merge will work if I have around 1 million rows in each point layer? it would add up to about 17 million points

Comment: If you are using a feature class, it shouldn’t be a problem, https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabase-size-and-name-limits.htm